# cordova: "Android SDK: not installed"

Tags: android, cordova, sdk

*I know there are many threads like this but none of them helped.*

I am using **Windows 10**, **Cordova 7.1.0** (latest version) and I have installed Android Studio with **SDK Platform 7.1.1 - API level 25** (also tried downgrading to 7.0 - API level 24). Also, I installed **SDK build-tools** using Android Studio SDK Manager.

Running:

```
cordova info
```

I get this message:

> Android SDK is not set up properly. Make sure that the Android SDK
>   'tools' and 'platform-tools' directories are in the PATH variable.
>
> 'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Running

```
cordova requirements
```

I get this message:

> Android SDK: not installed 
>   Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually. Detected 'adb' command at
>   C:\Windows but no 'platform-tools' directory found near. Try reinstall
>   Android SDK or update your PATH to include valid path to
>   SDK\platform-tools directory. Android target: not installed cmd:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: 'android' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file. Gradle: not installed Could not find gradle wrapper within
>   Android SDK. Could not find Android SDK directory. Might need to
>   install Android SDK or set up 'ANDROID_HOME' env variable.

I also tried to install manually the SDK, without Android Studio, but it did not help. I am not used to working with CLI's so I may be missing something.

However, I tried upgrading Cordova, downgrading SDK and installing the latter manually. I was also confused with environment variables, I tried some things I read but none worked. Any help, appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem and I think it is because of an old version of Android Studio and SDK that I installed back in 2014. `Detected 'adb' command at /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.6.2/bin`but my SDK is at Users/myname/Library/sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Seems that in my case, Java JDK 9 was causing the problem. Downgrading to JDK 8 gave me the solution.

In addition, I hadn't set the ANDROID_HOME variable correctly but even when I did, it did not work until downgrading to JDK 8.